# Finding the order of an element in a group $\mathbb{Z}_{12}$

Tags: group-theory

I'm trying to calculate the order of an element in a group. I saw a simple example: find the order of an element $3$ in $\mathbb{Z}_{12}$. First they wrote that $\langle 3 \rangle = \{0,3,6,9\}$ but I could not understand why. As I understand, we are looking for all the number $a\in \mathbb{Z}_{12}$ so there exists an $n\in  \mathbb{N}$ so $3^n=a$. So it should be $\langle 3 \rangle = \{3,9\}$ because there is no $n\in \mathbb{N}$ so $3^n=0$ or $3^n=6$. Am I missing something?

Also, is there a faster way to determine the order? What if I would like to calculate the order of $7$ when $\mathbb{Z}_{66}$?

Comment: In group theory notation.  There is one binary operation which may be written as $*$ or $\cdot$ or $\times$ or $+$ or $\circ$ or not written at all.  Then the notation $3^n$ means to apply that operation $n$ times.  In $\mathbb Z_{12}$ the operation is $*=+$.  So $3^0 =$ the identity equals $0$.  $3^1 = 3$.  $3^2 = 3*3=3+3 = 6$ and $3^3 = 3*3*3 = 3+3+3=9$ and $3^4 = 3*3*3*3= 3+3+3+3 = 0$.  We can go one step weirder and not $3^k = k\times 3$.  Because the group is about addition multiplication ... doesn't exist... not in the current universe.

Comment: Note that the multiplicative group normally associated with the integers modulo $12$ would involve the positive integers less than $12$ and having no factor in common with $12$ ie $\{1, 5, 7, 11\}$, and this set does not contain $3$. That is a decisive indication the additive group is intended. As you develop your knowledge of algebra you will encounter many cases (rings, fields  etc) in which both addition and multiplication feature. In the case of a field there is an additive group, and the non-zero elements make a multiplicative group. Normally there is an indication which is involved.

Answer (score 4):

I think your mistake with the theory is notational. In some group theory settings, "$3^n$" would represent the group operation combining the element with itself n times. This is just for convenience, as it looks cleaner to talk about elements in an abstract group like "$a^2b^3$", sort of how you would imagine integers being factored like primes.

Therefore, when the operation over the **set** $\mathbb{Z}_k$ is + , "$3^n$" really means "$3n$," where you use the standard quotient to take remainders (over k).

You might try and use the greatest common divisor to figure out how large the set is. You want to see how large the set is in question, but the set should be linear. It only "wraps around" after a certain point, which I believe occurs at $\frac{k}{\text{gcd}(a, k)}$ for an element "a" and a modulus "k."

Answer (score 2):

In a *group* we have an operation.  We don't know what the operation actually *IS* but it is an operation.

Now maybe we *shouldn't* but we tend to use the notation of multiplication. So we'll often write $a\in G; b \in G$ and $a*b = c$ as $ab = c$.  That doesn't actually mean the operation *is* arithmetic multiplication.  It could be *any* group operation.

We use the notation $a^k; a \in G; k \in \mathbb N$ to mean $\underbrace{a*a*a*a....*a}_{k\text{ times}}$.  This is similar to the concept of multiplication but the operation isn't necessarily arthemetical multiplication.  It is the group operation.

Perhaps we shouldn't.  If $*$ is not multiplication the $a^k$ is not multiplicative exponents.  But we are doing *ABSTRACT* algebra.  $*$ is not multiplication; it is any operation we want.  Aid $a^k$ is not *mmultiplicative* exponents.  It is exponents on *our operation whatever it is*.

And if our operation is ***ADDITION***, nothing changes.  $3^k = \underbrace{3 + 3+ .... + 3}_{k \text{ times}}$.

So

$3^2 = 3*3 = 3+3\pmod {12} = 6$.

And $3^3 = 3*3*3  = 3+3+3\pmod {12} = 9$.  And $3^4 = 3*3*3*3 = 3+3+3+3\pmod {12} = 0$.

In fact.  If $a*b = a + b\pmod {12}$ and $a^k = a+a+a..... + a \pmod {12} = k\times a \pmod {12}$.

The thing is... As for as the *additive* ***group*** $\mathbb Z_{12}$ goes the *only* operation we have is addition and multiplication does not exist.  So thinking of "powers" as exponents over multiplication just... doesn't make sense.  If anything they are "exponents of addition".

......

> Also, is there a faster way to determine the order? What if I would like to calculate the order of 7 when Z66?

Okay $7^2 = 7+7 = 2\times 7 = 14$ and ....

we want to find the *smallest* $k$ where $7^k = k\times 7 \equiv 0 \pmod {66}$.

Well, trial and error shows us $7^9 = 9\times 7 =63$ and $7^{10} = 10\times 7 = 70 \equiv 4 \pmod {66}$ and.... and $7^{19} =19\times 7 19 = 133\equiv 1 \pmod{66}$ and $7^{20} = 20\times 7 = 140 \equiv 8\pmod{66}$ and... sheesh, how long do we have to go?!

Oh, heck... here's a secret.

We want $7^k = k\times 7 \equiv 0 \pmod {66}$.

That means there is a $N$ so that $7k = 66N$.  So $k = \frac {66N}{7}$. Now $7$ is relatively prime to $66$ so $\frac m7$ must be an integer. so let $\frac N7 = v$.

Then $k = 66*v$.  So $\frac {k}{66} = v$.  The smallest possible $k$ is if $j = 66$ and indeed $7^{66} = 66\times 7 \equiv 0 \pmod{66}$ and we know that no *smaller* such number exists because.... well, $7$ and $66$ are relatively prime....

In general the formula if if $|a| = k$ in $\mathbb Z_m$ so that $a^k = 0 \implies k\times a = m\times N$ for some $N$ the smallest such $k$ that can do this is if $k\times a = m\times N$ is the least common multiple of $a$ and $m$.  ANd that would be when $k = \frac {m}{\gcd(a,m)}$.

Hence the formula you saw.  $|a| = \frac {|\mathbb Z_m|}{\gcd(a, |\mathbb Z_m|)}$.  (because $|\mathbb Z_m| = m$).

====

Actually John Nash's answer has a good insight for this.

$\mathbb Z_n$ is a cyclic group generated by $1$.  $a= 1+1+1....= 1^a$ and $a^k = 1^{ak}$ and $0 = 1^{nm}$ fr some $m$.

So the order $k$ of $a$ will be occur with $ak=nm$ is the least common multiple of $n$ and $a$.  I.E. if $k = \frac{n}{\gcd(n,a)}$.

(If you are curious what rule $m = \frac {a}{\gcd(n,a)}$ plays... well it doesn't really play any role.  It's how many times $a$ has to "double back" because its remainder doesn't divide "nicely" into $n$.  It's  ... only as significant as we want it to be.)

Comment: I saw the use of the following equation: $|x|=\frac{|\mathbb{Z_{m}}|}{gcd(|\mathbb{Z_{m}}|,x)}$. But for this question it will give us:  $|7|=\frac{66}{gcd(66,7)}=66$ and not $19$. Am I missing something again?

Comment: Argh... No!  You are right and I am wrong!  I made a very foolish mistake!  $1$ is *not* the identity for addition.  $0$ is the identity. (I was even going to point that out but I thought that would confuse things).  SO we want $7^k = e$ or $k\times 7 \equiv 0 \mod 66$ not $k\times 7 \equiv 1 \mod 66$.  !!!!  *BIG* difference!  ... I'm sorry and I'll fix it.

Comment: It's funny beecause in making the mistake $7^{19} =1$ I made the *exact* same mistake you did.  I forgot for a moment we were dealing with *ADDITION* and not multiplication.  Because this is addition we need $7^k = k\times 0 \equiv 0 \pmod{66}$.

Comment: I'm surprised no-one else caught me on this!

Comment: that's ok! thanks for the answer. Is there a similar formula for $\mathbb{Z}_{n}^{\times}$?

Comment: $\mathbb Z_n^\times\setminus\{0\}$ is only a group if $n$ is prime and only if $0$ is ommited. ($1$ is the identity and $a*b \equiv 1\pmod(n)$ won't have solutions unless $\gcd(b,n)=1$ and the only way to have all numbers relative to $n$ is if $n$ is prime.)  Then $a^{n-1}\equiv 1\pmod n$ and so $|a|$ will divide $n-1$.  A good guess is to see if start with $\frac {n-1}{2^k}$ and then double it.  Eventually $a^{\frac{n-1}{2^j}}\equiv -1$ and $a^{\frac{n-1}{2^{j-1}}}\equiv 1$.

Comment: @vesii fleablood is right. Note that you can also find orders for composite $n$, where you replace $a^{n-1}$ with $a^{\phi(n)}$, where $\phi(n)$ is the Euler phi function. This is a more general theorem since for a prime $p$, $\phi(p) = p - 1$, and the division works out the same. But only the set of units forms a group in a composite modulus.

Comment: "you can also find orders for composite n, where you replace an−1 with aϕ(n), where ϕ(n) is the Euler phi function. "  ... *and* where $\gcd(a,n) = 1$.  However you can use chinese remainder theorem to find "quasi-orders" where $a^k \equiv \gcd(a,n) \pmod n$. (i.e. $\frac a{\gcd(a,n)}^k \equiv 1 \pmod{\frac n{\gcd(a,n)}}$ and $k$ divides $\phi (\frac n{\gcd(a,n)})$.  (Maybe we are getting ahead of ourselves).

Comment: I find it more interesting that if $n$ is prime then $\mathbb Z_n$ is a field. so both $\mathbb Z_n^+$ and $\mathbb Z_n^\times \setminus\{0\}$ are groups.  If $n$ is not prime then $\mathbb Z_n$ is a ring with identity.  Under addition it's a group but under multiplication it has zero divisors and not every element has an inverse (and thus not an order either).

Answer (score 1):

*$\mathbb{Z}_{12}$ is a cyclic group under addition. So the generator $'a'$ of the form $<a>={na |~ for ~some n\in \mathbb{Z}}$.
In order to find order  of $3$ we need to do as follows:
$<3>=\{3,6,9,0\}=\{0,3,6,9\}$
here $n=4$ for which $<3> $is zero. Hence order of $3$ is $4$.*

Comment: This answer has a very good insight.  I think the OP would do well to consider it.